# Laravel Eloquent How to update data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have controller where i have funtion to update data now i want to test this with postman, but unfortunately its not updating and i dont know where i am wrong here is my code
Route code :

```
Route::put('/fcmtoken_referesh', ['uses' => 'EmployeesController@fcmtoken_referesh']);
```

function code

```
public function fcmtoken_referesh(Request $request){
        $postArray = ['fcm_token' => $request->fcm_token];
        $login = Employee::where('api_token',$request->api_token)->update($postArray);

        if ($login) {

            return 'true';

        }else{

            return 'false';

        }

    }
```

and here is screenshot how i am updating data from postman kindly correct me if i am wrong from any side
[image: postman]

so basically i want to send api_token and based on that api_token fcm_token should update, so i am sending two parameteres api_token to get data and fcm_token to update fcm_token field in table

Comment: A 405 error means your route is not registered correctly.  Post the related output of `php artisan route:list`

Comment: I believe you are accessing the `public` url in your postman, and think you've your `api` route defined in `routes/api.php`